# What is the difference between certain fields of entities in the Common Data Model (CDM) for sales?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, common-data-service

While studying the CDM models for sales and mapping my data to different fields, I was confused about what is the difference between some fields like `totalDiscountAmount` and `discountAmount` in Order entity and between `ownerId` and `owningUser`. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Do you have follow up questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all these details in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/salesorder?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9#properties).

> `discountamount`: Type the discount amount for the order if the customer is eligible for special savings.

> `totaldiscountamount`: Shows the total discount amount, based on the discount price and rate entered on the order.

`ownerid` is of principal type, which can hold the value of either team or systemuser internally in `owningteam` or `owninguser` respectively - useful in security concepts across the CDS product. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/principal?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9)